# Calling modelica model in C++

Tags: c++, modelica, openmodelica

Currently, I have a modelica model that takes certain continuous pulse signal as input and simulates some behaviour and gives boolean outputs. I know modelica can call external functions but is there a convinient way to "pack" a modelica model into something so i can call it in my other c++ code? I have looked into fmi but so far I can only co-simulate my model with matlab and I am a bit confused on how to use the exported fmu file.

Comment: or can C++ load and run a fmu created by openmodelica? the main goal is to receive inputs and feed outputs to an external program written in c++.

Comment: see http://www.jmodelica.org/FMILibrary how to call FMUs from C/C++. You can also look into FMU Cheker on some code how to call FMUs: https://github.com/modelica-tools/FMUComplianceChecker

Comment: I feel like making my C++ program FMI supportive is a bit of overkill in my case especially since I'm still a beginner. Is there a more simpler way to exchange data between my model and the program? I'm thinking of using external functions in modelica to read/write information to a seperate file.

Comment: Especially for a beginner I would strongly recommend using FMI. If you look at the simple simulator of the FMU SDK, you will see that this will be only a few lines of code.